# javascript - inserting text from a div to an api call for embed

Tags: javascript, embed

i have the following basic script to make an api call to vimeo and insert the embed to a div #embed.  I'm having trouble however getting it to grab the text of another div #embedthis and assembling the api call from that.

The code below does work if placed in the `<body>`.  However I want to set this up properly as I would like to also be able to change the content of #embedthis dynamically, updating the displayed embed.  Any help is so much appreciated!

script:

```
  // URL to get embed
  var videoUrl = document.getElementById('embedthis').innerHTML; 

  // oEmbed endpoint for Vimeo using JSON

  var endpoint = 'http://www.vimeo.com/api/oembed.json';

  // Tell Vimeo what function to call
  var callback = 'embedVideo';

  // Put together the URL
  var url = endpoint + '?url=' + encodeURIComponent(videoUrl) + '&callback=' + callback + '&width=640';

  // put video on page
  function embedVideo(video) {
      document.getElementById('embed').innerHTML = unescape(video.html);
  }

  // load data from Vimeo
  function MakeEmbed() {
      var js = document.createElement('script');
      js.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
      js.setAttribute('src', url);
      document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0).appendChild(js);
  };

  window.onload = MakeEmbed;
```

view:

```
<div id="embed">
  ...
</div>

<div id="embedthis">http://vimeo.com/24453255</div>
```

With this I get `document.getElementById('embedthis')" is null`, probably because #embedthis isn't loaded yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that when `var videoUrl = document.getElementById('embedthis').text()` is called, the `<div>` has yet to be created by the browser, since this code is called as soon as the browser encounters it, which I assume is in your `<head>` section.

Your code should work if you move it to a function which is called on `window.onload` or `document.ready` as this guarantees that the element has been created.

**Edit**

Like so (comments removed for brevity):

```
var url;
function embedVideo(video) { ... }

var my_onload = function() {
    var videoUrl = document.getElementById('embedthis').innerHTML; 
    var endpoint = 'http://www.vimeo.com/api/oembed.json';
    var callback = 'embedVideo';
    url = endpoint + '?url=' + encodeURIComponent(videoUrl) + '&callback=' + callback + '&width=640';
    MakeEmbed();
}

window.onload = my_onload;
```

Comment: I do think you're right that i need a function that doesnt look for embedthis before it's ready.  I just edited my post with code that DOES work as expected if i put it at the bottom of the <body> to test it.  I just can't figure out how to structure the function properly to only look for `'embedthis'` once the DOM is loaded, while making sure that all of the other script also has access to that variable.

Comment: Nice, yeah that's what I did pretty much.  Only I was able to keep var url in the main function for whatever reason(?) and now I just trigger the action with an onclick call from a button in the html.  works well now.  Thanks!